# How to ask for root password from the user for my GUI app which pipes it to makepkg?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, flatpak, aur, rust

I was learning rust. I am building a simple GUI application that scrapes through aur and installs a package. I am using tauri for GUI.

So, to install an aur application, I will run `makepkg -si` inside the package directory.
But, it asks for root password in the middle of installation.
After searching web, I came to know, I can use pkexec to ask password graphically but pkexec is like using sudo and running makepkg as sudo is not allowed.

Any idea of what should I do? Are there any articles where I can look into ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, to install an aur application, I will run makepkg -si inside the package directory. But, it asks for root password in the middle of installation. After searching web, I came to know, I can use pkexec to ask password graphically but pkexec is like using sudo and running makepkg as sudo is not allowed.

makepkg *itself* uses sudo when necessary. It never asks you for a password directly; it just calls `sudo` or `doas` when it has to invoke pacman.

So if sudo is being used, you can e.g. set the `SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable to some program that would display the password prompt.

You can also set `PACMAN_AUTH` through your ~/.config/pacman/makepkg.conf to have it use pkexec instead.

Answer (score -1):

Usage of graphical AUR helpers may lead to a defective system, for example through unattended [partial upgrades](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported). That being said, I would recommended looking at [paru](https://github.com/morganamilo/paru) being a rust aur helper to get to know how to make/use a aur helper in rust